# Get Facebook profile pictures album

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to retrieve all profile pictures for a user in facebook. So far, I've found that I have to look in "me/albums", and the album I want is the only one of `type: 'profile'`.

I also found that I cannot filter on the `type`. So it seems to me the only way is retrieving all albums, then searching for the one I want. But let's say my user have tons of albums, and the first response from facebook does not contain the album I want. I then have to make another request to get the next page.

My questions are :

- Is there really no way to filter on the `type`?
- Can I make assumptions about "where" (page wise) the profile pictures album will be?

Currently we are retrieving all (max 300) albums and looking on them after, but it takes too much time. Hence the questions, we need to optimize this part. For what it's worth, it's a rails 3 app with Koala handling facebook interactions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/fql?q=select+aid+from+album+where+owner=me()+and+type="profile"&access_token=...
```

**update**

This will return you directly only the profile pictures:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/fql?q=select+pid,src_small+from+photo+where+aid+in(select+aid+from+album+where+owner=me()+and+type="profile")&access_token=...
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. I don't know why I got an error when using `WHERE type='profile'` when I tried earlier though..

Comment: If making other graph API calls, you may want the object_id instead of the "aid":

SELECT object_id FROM album WHERE owner=me() and type="profile"

Comment: For some reason the FQL isn't working for me - and I have been using the Graph explorer to try it out.  Any chance you could reformat it?

Comment: Versions after 2.0 will not support FQL: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/

Comment: as of Agust 8, 2016 FQL will no longer work. We have to Graph API.

Answer (score -1):

No, there's no way to retrieve the Profile Photos albums specifically in Graph API; but you'll get the current profile pic easily as its returned in the user's basic information.

Why not just retrieve all album names in one call (`/me/albums?fields=name&limit=500`) and loop through them in code? It can't take that long really, can it?

{edit} Alexander's solution should work too, I haven't checked it though

Comment: The looping can be very very slow.